# The Creation of The Encryption Key for a Keyword Cipher in My Code (Java)

Tags: java, encryption

I was just wondering if I could get some help with a question involving keyword ciphers.

The following code is supposed to create the encryption key for a keyword cipher (the key that states how your input (let's say "this is a secret message") became ("qabp bp k poynoq hoppkdo")). The key is, therefore, a String or char array. My teacher had us use a char array. For the case above, the key would `{KEYWORDABCFGHIJLMNPQSTUVXZ}`, and the basic alphabet would correspond to this `{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}`, therefore `A` would become `K`, I would become `A`, and so on and so forth.

But, anways, back to the problem at hand, when I try to create the key, the first loop that you see below works perfectly fine adding in the keyword for the first values of the array; however, after this adding in the rest of the array (the rest of the alphabet not including or skipping the letters of the keyword) doesn't seem to work in the second loop.

I don't exactly know what I am doing wrong, but I would guess it would have to do with one of the if statements, or the java keyword (`continue;`) that I use in the loop. Because it appears that when I print the keyword `array`, it comes out to `{KEYWORDABCDEFGHIJKLMONPQRS}` leaving out the last seven letters of the alphabet instead of the letters that already occur in the word, `KEYWORD`.

If you could help fix the code, or get me on the right track, that would be much appreciated. If you have an question on the question, fell free to ask in the comment section below/

Thank you so much for all your help!

```
public class Crytograph
{
    private String in;
    private String out;
    //private int awayFrom;
    private char [] keyword;
    private String word;
    public Crytograph(String input, String wordLY) // , int fromAway )
    {
        in = input.toLowerCase();
        out = "";
        awayFrom = fromAway;
        word = wordLY;
        keyword = new char[26];
        int counter = 97;
        int counter1 = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < word.length(); x++)
        {
            keyword[x] = word.charAt(x);
        }
        for (int i = word.length(); i < 26; i++)
        {
            if ((char)(counter) == keyword[counter1])
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                keyword[i] = (char)(counter);
                //System.out.println(keyword[i]);
            }
            counter++;
            counter1++;
            if (counter1 == word.length())
            {
                counter1 = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you have any questions in regards to the question, please fell free to ask in the comment section below. Thank you!

Comment: Does this if ever evaluate to true? try printing (char)(counter) inside.

Comment: Yes, it does evaluate to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're comparing each new character to a *single* character at index `counter1`. But you really need to compare it to *all* the characters in `word`. Even if you happen to find a match, `continue;` will still increment `i`, meaning your array will be missing one or more characters at the end. Try this instead:

```
char c = 'a' - 1;
for (int i = word.length(); i < 26; i++) {
    // loop until we find a char not contained in `word`
    while (word.contains(String.valueOf(++c)));
    keyword[i] = c;
}
```

Comment: I understand what you want to do (comparing it to all characters in the variable word) for a reason though this code doesn't end up fixing my problem or that problem. As I stated before in the question, the array keyword was supposed to end up equaling {keywordabcfghijlmnpqstuvxz}, but with this solution the array equals {keyword    f      l    p    s  xz}. I might have the space amount a tad off, but that was about what the array was now equal too. You maybe made a small error in the code that you were trying to convey. If you could please edit your answer, or provide a new solution.

Comment: I did make a small mistake in the original version of this answer. Make sure you're using the current snippet.

Comment: Oh, I also just realized what the probably with the code is now. See, now the array equals {keyword   de     k   o   r    w y}, but the array should be {keywordabcfghijlmnpqstuvxz}. So, I think you meant to do:                         (!(word.contains(String .calueOf(c++)))

Comment: I just tested my previous statement and that doesn't work either, which is very puzzlilng, because I would think it would. Now, it gives me an array of {keywordc jnqvxc jnqvxc jnq). Again, the spacing between each "word" is a little off, but that was the basically the array.

Comment: I understand how it would work, and obviously that website's compiler is correct, but for some reason I am not getting the correct output with my compiler. This is a school (computer science) computer, as well so I would highly doubt that the bluejay program's compiler on here is not working correctly. So, I think that maybe I am just somehow outputting the wrong thing. My code for how I output the problem with be below, just tell me if you see any issue on why we are getting seperate answers.

Comment: class Crytograph
{
 private String in;
 private char [] keyword;
 private String word;
 public Crytograph(String input, String wordLY, int fromAway)
     in = input.toLowerCase()
     awayFrom = fromAway;
     word = wordLY;
     keyword = new char[26];
     for (int x = 0; x < word.length(); x++)
     {
         keyword[x] = word.charAt(x);
     }
     char c = 'a' - 1;
     for (int i = word.length(); i < 26; i++)
     {
         while ((word.contains(String.valueOf(++c))))
         {
             keyword[i] = c;
         }
     }
     System.out.println((keyword));
 }

Comment: I know that I am missing a few semicolon, and thinks like that, but that was simple just to fit the code all in comment. My punctuation is correct in my real class, and I have no errors, before, after, or while the program is taking place.

Comment: `keyword[i] = c;` shouldn't be in the `while` block. It should run after the inner loop.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I actually thought that was a typo in the code, but I understand know. That was my fault. Thank you so much for all of your help with the question.

Comment: Oh, and one more quick question if it is not to much trouble? I know how to encode a message by using the key, but how would I decode a message, in other words, what would the method (let's say the method, public void decode or public String decode) look like (how would I convert the encoded message, qabp bp k poynoq hoppkdo to the decoded message, this is a secret message, using a method).

Comment: That's a little too broad for this comment section.

Comment: I understand that. Could I move this into a discussion and you could help me there, or should I make a new question? And if I do make a new question, do you mind answering it?

Comment: Make a new question. I can't promise to answer it.

Comment: Please [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you.

Comment: Yes, I will accept this answer, sorry for taking so long to understand it. Thank you for all your help though! If you can answer the other question too, that would be great, if not I complete understand.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Comment: If you can or want to help, the link for the new question in just below this sentence: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46535923/how-to-decode-a-keyword-cipher-in-java